# Merging Two large Arrays into one Array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to merge two Large Array into one single Array.

Array is in **nested** form like -

```
Array_1 = [["",""],["",""],["",""],....]
Array_2 = [["",""],["",""],["",""],....]
```

the size of each Array is about 25mb.

Comment: `merged = [...Array_1, ...Array_2]` to combine the two

Comment: You...combine them. `.concat` or a `for` loop can do that. If you have any other requirements, you have to make them clear.

Comment: I have tried array.concat and for loop but its not giving me desired result, may be because of array size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: I need to merge nested array like [[["":""],["":""]],[],[],....]

Comment: Your example of the needed result (`[[["":""],["":""]],[],[],....]`) is confusing: it has invalid syntax. Can you make more clear example of the needed result?

Answer (score 1):

The ES6 way (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
let newArray = [...Array_1, ...Array_2];
```

the old school way:

```
let newArray = Array_1.concat(Array_2);
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.I need to merge two nested array like [[["":""],["":""]],[],[],....]

Comment: which one did you try? i am using the spread operator since many years, and it always worked fine for merging two array, no matter what´s inside. what node.js version are you using?

Comment: what means "did not work", what did the resulting array look like? i would rather use the ES6 way though, not the old one.

Comment: ...and use node.js 10, if possible. the spread operator should even work for arrays with node.js 5+ though, according to node green.